# get hyperlink list from database column in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, hyperlink, label

I am having 1 project website (quotes website)
I have a page where all the quotes are displayed to gather. (screenshot below).
I used stored procedure to display this result.

[image]

Now my main problem:

As you can see there is a field for tags 
eg: tags: Life, Funny, Leadership, Inspirational, Friendship

But this value comes from database column category. and i am using a single label to display these all categories.

But i want to divide it in individual category and redirect user on that particular category on which he clicks.

Is there any way i can divide this single label in multiple hyperlinks?

My stored procedure (in-case any1 needs)

```
ALTER Proc text_quotes
    (
    @cat varchar(50)
    )
as
begin
    select p.id,p.title,p.description,p.category,p.metadescp,p.metatitle,p.tags,f.img
    from tbl_upload_image p
    inner join tbl_author f
    on p.description = f.name
    where p.category like '%' + @cat + '%'
    order by p.upload_date desc
end
```

Example entry from database:

id  : 12

Quote   : dghjn

category: Life, Funny, Leadership, Inspirational, Friendship

author  : Jim Carrey

UPDATE:

i HAVE USED BELOW CODING:

```
foreach (DataListItem item in DataList4.Items)
        {
            Repeater RepeaterQ = ((Repeater)(item.FindControl("Repeater1")));
            string categories = ((Label)(item.FindControl("categoryLabel"))).ToString();

            // Label lblCategory = ((Label)(DataList4.FindControl("categoryLabel")));
            string[] arr1 = categories.Split(',');

            RepeaterQ.DataSource = arr1;

            RepeaterQ.DataBind();
        }
```

But i am getting "System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label " as text in repeater. Any help?

Comment: I have to divide these categories after i select it from the database as i use only single column "category" to store all the categories selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your category data in a variable like `categories` then I suppose you are assigning in to a label `lblCategory` as an example.

```
lblCategory.Text = categories;
```

If you are doing like that then you can try this.

```
lblCategory.Text = String.Join("", 
     categories.Split(new char[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) //Split Category csv to array of categories
    .Select(x=>String.Format("<a href='page.aspx?cat={0}'>{0}</a>"), x)) // return all categories with formatted anchor tag
    .ToArray() // Convert To Array
); //Join with empty string and assign to label text property
```

First split your categories with comma, and then use **.[Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx)** Linq Extension method to return a formatted hyperlink, and join these links and assign to label.

or you can use repeater there to bind your categories.

**UPDATED:**

```
foreach (DataListItem item in DataList4.Items)
{
    Repeater RepeaterQ = ((Repeater)(item.FindControl("Repeater1")));
    //string categories = ((Label)(item.FindControl("categoryLabel"))).ToString();
    string categories = ((Label)(item.FindControl("categoryLabel"))).Text;
    string[] arr1 = categories.Split(',');
    RepeaterQ.DataSource = arr1;
    RepeaterQ.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: have to use it in asp.net c#

Comment: Yes, It will work in asp.net 3.5, you need to add reference for Syatem.Linq. and `Select(x=>String.Format("<a href='page.aspx?cat={0}'>{0}</a>"), x))` is Linq Extension method, and here x is representing each category as string.

Comment: please have a look at the update i have posted in my que. If you can help. Thanks

Comment: i have used repeater to bind the categories as you said

Comment: <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">  
    <ItemTemplate>  
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink29" Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>'  runat="server"></asp:HyperLink> 
        <br />  
    </ItemTemplate>  
</asp:Repeater>

Comment: used hyperlink as i have to redirect the user

Comment: check updated answer, replace `((Label)(item.FindControl("categoryLabel"))).ToString();` with `((Label)(item.FindControl("categoryLabel"))).Text;`

Comment: you are rite. . . oops i ws so stupid how can i 4got to add .text..... Thanks a lot